# Non-compiling Equal Type

Tags: typescript

Reading [Building Complex Types in TypeScript Part 2](https://medium.hexlabs.io/building-complex-types-in-typescript-804c973ce66f)has the following code for Equal Type that does NOT compile for me:

**A Type Level Equals**

```
type Equal<A, B> = 
  (<T>() => T extends A ? true : false)
  extends 
  (<T>() => T extends B ? true : false)
    ? true
    : false;
```

It has several compilation errors. The type is then used subsequently to solve another problem.

Looking for help to solve it as I am digging deeper into TS types.

Comment: [Just need to rearrange the lines a bit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsA8BBANFAQgPigF4oAoKKACjQBV9KBKYwmqCAD2AgDsATAZygYoAfijAATgmgAuKADNU-CEw5c+g8lVr0mRFm048BeUeKmyFSlVopjJ021DmKUygNykgA)

Comment: ...and the new arrangement?

Comment: ...click on the link?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you are running into automatic semicolon insertion for conditional types.  Remove the a line break before `extends` and things will work:

```
type Equal<A, B> =
    (<T>() => T extends A ? true : false) extends // okay
    (<T>() => T extends B ? true : false)
    ? true
    : false;
```

---

JavaScript, and therefore TypeScript, has the "feature" where you are *sometimes* allowed to omit an otherwise required semicolon at the end of a statement if it appears at the end of a line; the language will "helpfully" insert semicolons at the ends of lines for you.   This is known as [automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion).

In practice this means that you can't always add line breaks everywhere whitespace would normally be allowed; if it is syntactically valid for a semicolon to appear where you've placed a line break, the language might insert one for you.  Isn't that nice?

Because [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) are of the form `AAA extends BBB ? CCC : DDD` where `AAA` is a valid type, and since `extends` is apparently a valid property name:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string
    extends: number; // <-- okay
}
```

then the TypeScript compiler sees a possible automatic semicolon insertion hazard before the `extends` keyword in a conditional type.  You're not allowed to put a line break there.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#21649](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21649) for the pull request that implemented this.

If you remove the line beak before `extends`, your code will compile as desired.

Note that this line break was not present [in the original document from which you copied this type](https://medium.hexlabs.io/building-complex-types-in-typescript-804c973ce66f#a967); you (or your non-TS-compliant code formatter) must have inserted it and caused this problem.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsA8BBANFAQgPigF4BYAKCkqgAo0AVfagSmMLqggA9gIA7AEwDOUDFAD8UYACcE0AFxQAZqkEQWXHgOEB6bVAD2AayQhyVGvUYsibDtz5C84yTPlKVas1QnTZXygrKKKoA3OTkAJa8PFLKAMbQAGL6+lAA3v5QSAqC0lEA5pkaDoIKvAgAtgBGEFIhULpQaAC0zQbGpmQAvuFkvEgVEIJgSAlQAHL6kOmZoNPwyOjYeISkFOZUtAzMrFDsxVoizr5uQaosmeYHjo28+sDtJplbVrv79oe4x65QgR5Ml28Lj86w2v3cwQgYW6QA)